# Share variables (arrays) between scripts and a few PHP server like scripts

Tags: php, websocket

I am running a few PHP websocket server scripts. Basically the server scripts should run 24h.
They should be able to access a not so large array like object, maybe 2k to 5k items. The PHP server like scripts should be able to write/read the shared array.
Other PHP scripts (triggered by async random ajax calls) should be able to read/write the shared array. I did some tests with shmop and I am not happy with the fact that I need to serialize data to be stored as string and I am worried about concurrency.
I have no idea how to proceed. Performance should by the main goal, not data security.  Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know what the format of the data is, but you could use a memory data store like Redis.

Comment: Thank you, I will try Redis, I did try with PostgreSQL, within an unlogged table and I computed the time consumed to access data from the server during a full loop of the server script and it takes most of the time. Do you have any idea how fast should I expect Redis to perform compared to PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's stored in memory, so unless you can store the database in memory in PostgreSQL, it will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better solution for storage, in situation you've described, than shared memory.

If you care only for access time to bulk data SHM is your "go for it".
You can simply create wrapper to maintain serialization and storage in your code.

If there is need for storage and access data in certain manner (indexed / sorted) you should try something like sqlite with files stored on tmpfs/ramfs (in memory).

Comment: You are correct about serialization, I did some tests and it is 150 to 200 times faster compared to running a query on current PostgreSQL database. Also writing/reading string to/from shared memory segment is very fast. My only concerns are concurrency and variable size of the serialized representation. Should I reserve a large enough  memory segment? Is if safe to use open shared memory segment from more scripts at the same time and read/write data to it? Can I check if shared segment is open and force scripts trying to update into a loop until segment is closed?